# How do I create a node class with a pointer to a parent node that I can make null

Tags: c++

Never mind I am an idiot

My current node class

```
class node
{
public:
    int xCoord;   // current position
    int yCoord;
    int gCost;     //Cost to travel to node
    int hCost;
    int parentX;  // parent coordinates
    int parentY;
    node* parentNode;

    node(int x, int y, int g , int h, int pX, int pY, node* parent) 
        {xCoord=x; yCoord = y; gCost = g; hCost = h; parentX = pX; parentY = pY;   parentNode = parent;}

    int getxCoord() const {return xCoord;}
    int getyCoord() const {return yCoord;}
    int getgCost() const {return gCost;}
    int getfCost() const {return hCost;}
    int getparentX() const {return parentX;}
    int getparentY() const {return parentY;}
```

I want to create a node like this

```
node* startNode = new node(startX, startY, 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
```

However it is giving me an identifier 'null' is undefined error

Comment: make your class names capital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `null` in C++.
There is [NULL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), there is `0` and there is [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) in C++11.

Comment: You should use nullptr wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks I've node had much sleep :P